# How to stop Intellij Idea to put @Transactional on interface method when I pull up its implementation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, interface, transactions, code-generation

Like in this method:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public boolean deleteConfigDictionary(Long id){
  return false;
}
```

After I add @Override to this method, Idea found there is no matching interface method in the interface. So it marks it as error and offer to pull it up:

[image]

But after the interface method is created, it automatically has @Transactional annotation, which is discouraged in Spring:

```
@Transactional
boolean deleteConfigDictionary(Long id);
```

How to avoid this? Would be helpful if I can choose what annotations are not pulled up or maybe just disable copying annotation.

Comment: there's an open ticket in IDEA's tracker for this, vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161642